# Issue with scrollviewer and canvas

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas, scrollviewer

I have a custom `canvas` control which sits inside a `scrollviewer` - I have implemented drag, drop and move for items on the `canvas` and overridden `MeasureOverride` so that when I move an item around on the canvas its size reflects the changes so if I move the item beyond the visible portion of the canvas it will resize to accommodate the moved item and scrollbars will show appropriately.

However if I then bring the item into view by using the scrollbars then start to move the item back out again the scrollbars go a bit haywire.

It's a rather poor explanation of the problem I afraid but I am not sure how else to put it but hopefully it will contain enough info for somebody to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, more explanation of problem is required. Although I was also in a situation where I faced a lot of issues with `Canvas` and `scroll-viewer`, look at this question for problems I faced and how I solved that -

[ScrollBars are not visible after changing positions of controls inside a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061400/scrollbars-are-not-visible-after-changing-positions-of-controls-inside-a-canvas)

> I had to use `base.InvalidateMeasure()`
>   explicitly after each operation to
>   refresh the canvas and make the
>   scrollbars visible.