# WPF questions (SizeChanged event, scrollviewer+canvas)

Tags: wpf

I am trying to put a ScrollViewer wrapped around a Canvas (a chart of some signals), but I can't seem to get it to work.

First of all, I have a user control that is a makes 2d line graphs (from a book that I'm following), and I am trying to modify it to customize it for my own uses. The relevant parts are:

My app (Window1.xaml)

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">

        <local:LineChartControlLib x:Name="originalChart" Xmin="0" Xmax="51.2" Ymin="-3" Ymax="3" Background="White" Title="" GridlinePattern="DashDot" />

    </Grid>
```

The UserControl:

```
    <Grid Margin="0" x:Name ="chartGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Transparent" SizeChanged="chartGrid_SizeChanged" />
    <Canvas Margin="2" Name="textCanvas" ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Canvas Name="chartCanvas" ClipToBounds="False">
            <Canvas Name="legendCanvas" Background="Transparent" />
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
```

If I put a ScrollViewer around any of the grids of canvas in my app, the canvas doesn't show and the execution time is terribly slow. If I put a ScrollViewer around the grid or the Canvas in the user control, the "chartGrid_SizeChanged" event gets fired repeatedly (infinitely). Can anyone enlighten me on what I am not understanding? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canvas panel doesn't work well with scrollviewers.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855334/wpf-how-to-make-canvas-auto-resize) for more information.