# How to Visible ScrollBar In Items Panel With Canvas as ItemsPaneltemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

In My Application I Have ItemsControl with Canvas as ItemsPanelTemplate. Items of itemspanel source is thumb object and can drag and drage. if items drop out of screen view , I dont can scroll to view them. How I Want To Do?
My Code Is Below :

```
            <ItemsControl ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XPosition}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YPosition}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to surround the `ItemsControl` with a `ScrollViewer` (unlike ListBox, which has it in its control template):

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl> ... </ItemsControl>
<ScrollViewer>
```

Secondly, a `Canvas` does not resize itself after its children. So you have a few options:

- Use a Grid with a single cell and set the positions using the `Margin` property.
- Calculate the maximum size and set the Canvas' `Width` and `Height` properties.
- Inherit from Canvas and override the MeasureOverride method so they reflect the children's sizes. (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7115788/276083).)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by setting/updating `Canvas`'s `Height`.