# WPF: position items in ItemsControl and enable scroll

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of objects with `X`,`Y` properties. I want to put the collection into `ItemsControl` and position each item according to its x and y.

I don't know the maximum of X or Y.

I tried to use `Canvas` as ItemsControl.ItemsPanel, but Canvas doesn't change its size based on its children. Thus ScrollViewer cannot scroll ItemsControl.

I checked [How to Visible ScrollBar In Items Panel With Canvas as ItemsPaneltemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772729/how-to-visible-scrollbar-in-items-panel-with-canvas-as-itemspaneltemplate). The first solution is to use Grid and set Margin. However, Thickness.X and Thickness.Y are not dependency properties and not bindable. The second solution is OK but involves code-behind. The last solution should also work but writing a new class is laborious.

How to position items in ItemsControl and enable scroll? What solution do you prefer?

Comment: bind the Canvas `Width` and Height` properties to properties in your ViewModel, and have the ViewModel calculate the required values. That's what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Shoe that doesn't  resolve the size of the canvas issue, what are you talking about?

Comment: There is a radar screen in the book "WPF Control Development Unleashed: Building Advanced User Experiences" which is built on the basis of a ListBox and a self-developed ItemsPanel. This panel poitions the items according to their coordinate and determines its preferred size from those coordinates. I am sure you find the source code for download somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Though Thickness.X and Thickness.Y are not dependency properties, Margin is. You just need to define a ValueConverter that accepts your object containing X and Y values, or a MultiValueConvert that accepts the X and Y values. Both implementations would return a Thickness.

```
<YourElement.Margin>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMarginConverter}">
      <Binding Path="X"/>
      <Binding Path="Y"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</YourElement.Margin>
```

.

```
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Validate parameters...

        Thickness margin = new Margin(values[0], values[1], 0d, 0d);

        return margin;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Validate parameters...

        double x = ((Thickness)value).Left;
        double y = ((Thickness)value).Top;

        return new object[]{x, y};
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but you get the picture. As far as which approach is better, using a Canvas sounds like more of a control designed for your intended purpose. However, it depends on the details of what you're trying to do. I believe canvas has potential for greater efficiency with virtualization if you're expecting a lot of points. If they don't need to be interactive, you could also just draw them to a bitmap image.