# Controls running away from Canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

I have the following XAML code:

```
<TabItem Header="Hey there, handsome!">
    <Canvas>
      <GroupBox Header="30" Canvas.Top="40">
        <Canvas>
          <Label Canvas.Top="40">dawd</Label>
        </Canvas>
      </GroupBox>
    </Canvas>
</TabItem>
```

I expect to see a GroupBox that is 40px from the top of the tab and **inside** the GroupBox a label that is 40px from its top.

But this happens:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

(All in all, I just need a layout panel for absolute positioning).

Comment: This might be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855334/wpf-how-to-make-canvas-auto-resize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this a Canvas behaviour, with Grid instead of Canvas that should work fine, and why not set the GroupBox Height and Width property to "Auto" ?

Comment: Grid is not ideal for absolute positioning. Setting the size of the GroupBox to "auto" doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, I used the Grid wrong (Setting the Top,Left,Width,Height properties instead of using only margins).

Comment: I meant something like this
    <TabItem Header="Hey there, handsome!">
            <Canvas>
                <GroupBox Header="30" Canvas.Top="40">
                    <Grid  Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                        <Label Margin="0,40,0,0">dawd</Label>
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
            </Canvas>
        </TabItem>