# Several Polylines in a Viewbox using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, polyline

I'd like to "draw" several `Polyline`s and some `Textblock`s or `Label`s in a `Viewbox` in WPF.

Since a `Viewbox` only allows a single Child, I tried to put the `Polyline`s inside a `Canvas` Element which didn't work:

XAML:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
     <Canvas Margin="10">
        <Polyline 
                        Points="{Binding Path=Points2}"
                        Stroke="Green"
                        StrokeThickness="2" >
        </Polyline>
                    <!-- other Polylines, Textblocks etc.  would go here... -->
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

The `Polyline` is correctly drawn when I use this code (i.e. I simply dropped the `Canvas`):

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Polyline 
                        Points="{Binding Path=Points2}"
                        Stroke="Green"
                        StrokeThickness="2" >
        </Polyline>
</Viewbox>
```

I want to visualize some geometric properties like in a very minimalistic computer geometry program like [geogebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra) for instance. Optionally some points should be movable in a next version, but this is not essential.

Solution:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
     <Grid>
        <Polyline 
                        Points="{Binding Path=Points2}"
                        Stroke="Green"
                        StrokeThickness="4" >
        </Polyline>
        <Polyline 
                        Points="{Binding Path=Points2}"
                        Stroke="Yellow"
                        StrokeThickness="2" >
        </Polyline>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

This puts to identical polygons on top of each other, i.e. thin yellow on top of wide green polyline.

The answer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855334/wpf-how-to-make-canvas-auto-resize) helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas doesn't really work for things like this, once you put your controls inside a canvas you ignore all layout. Can you instead put your poly lines inside a grid and use the margins to position them?

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid  Margin="10">
        <Polyline 
                    Points="{Binding Path=Points2}"
                    Stroke="Green"
                    StrokeThickness="2" >
        </Polyline>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: How could I put them on top of each other, i.e. if I put in two identical polygons: how could they placed on identical positions?

Comment: How could I use "positioning" margins that should contain negative values (not allowed for margins)?

Comment: They should be able to sit over each other just fine if you give them the same margin and negative margin is ok too.
 <Polyline Margin="-100,0,0,0"

Comment: Negative Margins didn't work for me. The docs also say they must not be negative: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't see your Polylines is because the `Canvas` has a default `Height` and `Width` of 0.

Try setting the `Height` and `Width` explicitly.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="ViewBox" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Canvas x:Name="chartCanvas" Margin="10" Height="200" Width="300">
        <Polyline 
                Points="{Binding Path=Points2}"
                Stroke="Green"
                StrokeThickness="2">
        </Polyline>
        <!-- other Polylines, Textblocks etc.  would go here... -->
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Ok. But what should I do if I want to determine the Canvas' size automatically? The polygons will change in size and I don't know the width/height in advance.

Comment: You could bind the Canvas Height and Width properties to a property on your ViewModel/Model that calculates the max size when the polygons are created.