# Autosize canvas in wpf

Tags: wpf, canvas, scrollviewer

How can canvas in wpf be autosized? I have a canvas in scrollviewer and I will add several buttons and lines in this canvas in code behind. since I don't know the position of the buttons, I have to hard code a very large number for the width and height of the canvas or if I add too many buttons, it can only show part of them.

I try to set the Width and Height to Auto but it doesn't work.

```
  <Grid>
      <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
          <Canvas Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="cv1"></Canvas>
      </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: duplicate question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855334/wpf-how-to-make-canvas-auto-resize?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: How to make canvas auto-resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855334/wpf-how-to-make-canvas-auto-resize)

Answer (score 1):

The `Canvas` element is the only element that can not be automatically resized, because has no inherent layout characteristics. If you want the `Control` to be resized as child elements come in, you could use something deriving from `Grid`. 
Try a `UniformGrid` instead of your `Canvas` ans fill it with the elements you want. It allows you to just add elements without any layout constraints that are handled by the `UniformGrid`. otherwise if you use a simple `Grid`, you will have to define a Position for your element by setting the `Margin` property of each child element.

Hope this helps.