# Render an Image from a StrokeCollection in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, inkcanvas

I need to get an Image from a StrokeCollection, but have no access to the Visual (InkCanvas) itself because of the mvvm structure. Is there possibly an easy way to get this done?

XAML:

```
<InkCanvas x:Name="paintSurface" Grid.Row="0" Opacity="0.2" Strokes="{Binding Strokes}">
    <InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes>
        <DrawingAttributes Color="Black" Width="10" Height="10"/>
    </InkCanvas.DefaultDrawingAttributes>
</InkCanvas>
```

Viewmodel:

```
private StrokeCollection _strokes;
public StrokeCollection Strokes {
    get => _strokes;
    set => SetProperty(ref _strokes, value);
}
```

Now i just want to convert the StrokeCollection into some form of processable Image, wether it is a Bitmap, BitmapImage, Mat, EmguCV Image, is not important.
Thx in advance :)

Comment: Did you have a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231819/saving-strokes-as-an-image-using-mvvm

Comment: You could rendertargetbitmap in the view. You "just" need to trigger that from the viewmodel or tell the viewmodel it's done. You probably won't want to exercise automated tests against a chunk of ui anyhow, but you couod encapsulate the code behind in a behavior if you wanted to re use it. Do you need pictures? You could extract the points out the strokes and build geometries use as data for paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my Problem by handing the StrokeCollection to a helper class where i just create a new InkCanvas, add the Strokes (from the Original InkCanvas in the UI) and render it.

```
public static Bitmap convertStrokestoImage(StrokeCollection strokes, int width, int height)
    {
        InkCanvas InkyStinky = new InkCanvas();
        InkyStinky.RenderSize = new System.Windows.Size(width, height);
        InkyStinky.Strokes.Add(strokes);
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(InkyStinky);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
        encoder.Save(stream);
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(stream);
        return b;
    }
```